# Finding if the current time is 72 hours more than the time that I get in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a variable `i` with it's value as `2020-02-04 10:15:35`

I want to check if the current datetime is at least 72 hours more than this given time stored in variable `i`

I tried with:

```
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if i > now - datetime.timedelta(hours=72):

            print(f"72 hours have passed")
```

Code seems to be skipping the if condition But is shouldn't in this case.

Trying it for the first time. How to tackle this? Where am I messing up?

Comment: `now - datetime.timedelta(hours=72)` is something like Feb. 17th. Is `2020-02-04` > `2020-02-17`…?!

Comment: oops. brutally messed up @deceze . I thought it must be some syntactical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way around. If `i` stores a `datetime` object, check

```
if i <= now - datetime.timedelta(hours=72):
    print("72 hours have passed")
```

You want to check if `i` is *earlier or equal* (less than or equal) to the difference, not later.

Comment: The difference doesn't really matter, but I liked your original approach with datetime subtraction better…

Comment: True, the logic was more clear, but I wanted to keep the OPs structure intact.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

Note: Ensure that `i` holds the `datetime` object

```
import datetime

i = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-02-22 10:15:35", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if i <= now - datetime.timedelta(hours=72):
    print(f"72 hours have passed")
```